# Working with preprocessing layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to build a layer that autonomously handles the preprocessing of categorical features of type string, I started by constructing the following function:

```
def encodingLayer(features):
lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(output_mode = "int",
                                      max_tokens = None,
                                      vocabulary = None)
lookup.adapt(features)
return(lookup.get_vocabulary())
```

and I get the following output:

```
encodingLayer(df)
['[UNK]',
'food',
'serious',
'not serious',
'nuts, nut products and seeds',
'fruits and vegetables',
...]
```

How can I integrate the `tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding()` function at this point to get a one-hot encoding?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def encodingLayer(features):
    lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(output_mode = "int",
                                  max_tokens = None,
                                  vocabulary = None)
    lookup.adapt(features)
    category_encoding = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(output_mode="one_hot", 
                                        num_tokens=len(lookup.get_vocabulary())+1)
    encoded_features = encoding_model(features)
    return encoded_features
```